# How to get value of the textarea in Gmail?

Tags: javascript, gmail, textarea

I need to get the value of the Gmail's textarea (the textarea where one write the email body).

Since I need to perform some I/O ops on the value of the text area I need to text to be formatted correctly.

Since I noticed that the value of the textarea in gmail is oddly **always** undefined (see img below)..

[image]

.. I started to implement some internal utilities to get the right HTML node, transform it into a string and extract the text out of it. I thought I'd be able to reproduce the original text formatting by searching for `<br>` tags and `&nbsp;`

Unfortunately, it's much more nuanced than this, there are much more edge cases that are hardly predictable.

Does anybody know if this is actually a solvable problem and if so, how?

Comment: There are two textareas on the page, use `textarea[0].value` or `textarea[1].value`. And yes, everything can be solved with js.

Comment: Gmail uses a contenteditable div instead of a traditional textarea, whose text you can get using 
`document.querySelector('div[contenteditable][aria-label="Message Body"]').innerText`

Comment: @JonasWilms there are actually 4 text areas in the page. The "message label" is the one I need. Looks like the structure the code quite randomly, it's hard to predict all the edge cases and maintain the formatting.

Comment: `var textarea = document.getElementsByClassName("Ak aXjCH")` return an array of tags. Do `textarea[index]` where `index` have the value 0,1,2,...... depending on the no. of tags with classname `Ak aXjCH`

Comment: @techfoobar you nailed it, thanks.

Comment: @iNullPointer right I see.

Comment: @techfoobar awesome. were you also able to pick the subject area?

Comment: @techfoobar 
I got it using :
document.getElementsByName("subjectbox")[0].value; 

I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish here but It seems like you need to change the content of a message and send it to using gmail message box and send the email
since you are using js you can try node js and try to scrape it using a web **scraper**

you will have to install node js and install "request" and "cheerio" dependencies and make a req to Gmail/compose mail and **scrape** that page and target the test area you want and append your message what ever you wan to do and internally post it

Comment: oh! so you can try above